# How to use Elasticsearch API ScriptQueryBuilder

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch 6.8.12, i need to add a update by query API in Java, i check docs in ES and know ScriptQueryBuilder can build script but i don't know how to use it, i searched in google and couldn't found any usable tutorial.

Share what i know currently:

1. we can use `_update_by_query` to update like Mysql `set extra= test where user='kimchy'`, refer to
   [es update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-update-by-query.html)

```
POST twitter/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.['extra'] = 'test'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

2. `ScriptQueryBuilder` can generate script query json,
   dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried below code but it run failed:

```
public String generateUpdateQuery() {
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(16);
        params.put("user","kimchy");
        Script script = new Script(Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TYPE, null, null, params);
        ScriptQueryBuilder scriptQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(script);
        System.out.println(scriptQueryBuilder.toString());
        return null;
}
```

**My requirement:**
I need to generate **script json** using `ScriptQueryBuilder` `QueryBuilders`, the ES API is `_update_by query`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

For sql:

```
{
    "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  },
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.extra = \"test\";",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

Code using `ScriptQueryBuilder`:

```
public String generateUpdateByQuery() {

BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(String.format("ctx._source.%s = %s;", "extra", String.format("\"%s\"","test")));


// if no params, keep it empty, it required in Script
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(16);
Script script = new Script(Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TYPE, "painless", sb.toString(), params);
ScriptQueryBuilder scriptQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.scriptQuery(script);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

// deal sql
JSONObject scriptOuter = JSON.parseObject(scriptQueryBuilder.toString());
JSONObject scriptJson = (JSONObject)scriptOuter.get("script");
JSONObject queryJson = JSON.parseObject(searchSourceBuilder.toString());
scriptJson.putAll(queryJson);
scriptJson.remove("boost");
// query:
return scriptJson.toJSONString()
}
```

If your query contains params like that:

```
 "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.extra = params.extraVal;",
        "lang": "painless"
        "params": {
            "extraVal":"test"
        }
    }
```

Then set params in the above map `params`

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(16);
params.put("extraVal","test")
Script script = new Script(Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TYPE, "painless", sb.toString(), params);
```

Comment: Thanks ! But we are still writing "ctx._source.%s = %s;" as a String value, does ScriptQueryBuilder have a DSL to build?

Comment: Hi @AlpcanYıldız, I used ES low level API to build dsl string, if you want to use it, you can use high level API to build dsl. You can joint dsl string or use `XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()` to build dsl.
See [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-put-stored-script.html](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-put-stored-script.html)